# Performance impact of enabling topic statistics

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, performance

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS [Topic Statistics](http://wiki.ros.org/Topics#Topic_statistics) are great for monitoring every topic on the system. Tools such as [ARNI](http://wiki.ros.org/arni) rely on topic statistics to be enabled at all times during normal operation.

Does anyone know what kind of performance impact there is to having `enable_statistics` set to True all the time?

Think of the following use case:
I want to know the publish stats (frequency, data age) of a high-density Lidar driver output. I could subscribe to the pointcloud using a monitoring node, but this means the monitoring node would receive the entire pointcloud payload even though it doesn't need it. This seems rather inefficient, all it needs to know is if something was published or not and when.

Is that the purpose of topic statistics? a lightweight way to dump out all topic activity?

Just wondering if `enable_statistics` is something that was designed for debug only or something that could be left on at all times. I also couldn't find a [REP](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0000.html) that discusses topic statistics, if I missed something, please let me know.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/283894/performance-impact-of-enabling-topic-statistics/) by [IanCol](https://answers.ros.org/users/26764/iancol/) on ROS Answers with karma: 253 on 2018-02-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

topic statistics happen in the publisher, so they're a lot lower overhead than subscribing to the topic. Not quite zero overhead, but they shouldn't be too noticeable on the average system.

Of course, every system is different, and the only way to know is to profile your system with topic statistics enabled and disabled, and compare the results.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2018-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [IanCol](https://answers.ros.org/users/26764/iancol/) on 2018-02-28**:
Thanks! just the clarification I was looking for. I'll try some profiling and see how it looks.